# Private REST API on django rest framework

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I am developing rest apis using `django-rest-framework` I am trying to put the spammers away from the API, so I decided I would have a secret token on header which will be known to only android client developer.

So, I will write a middleware that will examine the request headers, if that secret token is found continue the request, otherwise raise **Bad Request**

Does something like this already provided by the Django Rest Framework? If not, is my idea of writing a middleware is a good choice?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does something like this already provided by the Django Rest Framework?

A standard style for doing this sort of thing in REST framework would be to write a [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#custom-permissions) to deny access unless the header is set appropriately.

Your middleware approach would also work just as well, though.

Comment: WoW, Reply from the man himself. Thank you Tom. Best of luck for the kickstarter campaign.

Comment: Does that mean that if someone sets the header from, say, postman, can access the api? At least from front-end, on the browser, one can easily examine the header and mimic that request